# Extract all non zero values from a column

Tags: r

I have a matrix with n number of columns with zero and non-zero values:

```
A  B  C
1  3  0
2  4  0
0  0  3
```

I want to extract all non zero values from column c and assign it to a new matrix or data frame. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: What would be the dimension of the resulting matrix?

Comment: `dat[dat[, 'c'] != 0, 'c', drop=FALSE]`

Comment: Dimension are 86 rows by 11 columns

Comment: Jay the was helpful, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
m2 <- m
m2[m2[,3] == 0, 3] <- NA
m2
#      A B  C
# [1,] 1 3 NA
# [2,] 2 4 NA
# [3,] 0 0  3
m2[,3,drop = FALSE]
#       C
# [1,] NA
# [2,] NA
# [3,]  3
```

---

Data

```r
m <- structure(c(1L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L), .Dim = c(3L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("A", "B", "C")))
```